# Reseting PSN Password to access old account on PS4?

Tags: ps4, psn

I created an account, on my PS3, but then I created another account and forgot my old account's password. Now, I am trying to transfer my old account to my PS4.

I know my Online ID, and I know my Sign-In ID, but ***I still don't remember the password***.

**What else can I do to access my account  on  my PS4?**

Answer (score 2):

Try following the instructions on [this page.](https://support.us.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2539/~/change-and-reset-password)
If I remember correctly you may need your birth date and if for some reason you didn't use your real one you can also have their support team walk you through a password reset (they won't/can't(?) tell you what your old password was, for obvious reasons).

Comment: I've been through a similar process with my PS3. Thankfully, working with Sony tech support was a pretty quick and painless process.